# IllegalArgumentException / SpelEvaluationException even after compiling with -parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a parent project with pluginManagement. I have added the -parameters in the parent project as follows:

[Maven Plugin configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDAnK.png)

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

In the child projects I still see these IllegalArgumentException / SpelEvaluationException errors.
I even tried with adding the -parameters option in child projects plugin. Even after that these errors persist.
I am completely stuck with upgrade to Spring 6.1. Everything works fine with Spring 6.0.x but upgrading to Spring 6.1 is becoming painful.

I am using Spring Boot 3.2.4 & Spring 6.1.5

Can someone please help?

Tried compiling with -parameters flag set to true and was expecting the application to run smoothly but encountered the above mentioned errors